# Log is not getting printed in Flume server console

Tags: client-server, flume, log4j2

I have a standalone java application which uses log4j2 to print the logger statements.
I have configured flume client and flume server. Flume server is working fine. When I
run the java application, I get the connection created in server but the logger statements
are not getting printed.

Here is the logger statements in Flume server console:

```
INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-5] (org.apache.flume.source.AvroSource.start:168)  - Avro source r1 started.
INFO  [pool-7-thread-1] (org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer$NettyServerAvroHandler.handleUpstream:171)  - [id: 0x00633e5e, /127.0.0.1:56177 => /127.0.0.1:8800] OPEN
INFO  [pool-8-thread-1] (org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer$NettyServerAvroHandler.handleUpstream:171)  - [id: 0x00633e5e, /127.0.0.1:56177 => /127.0.0.1:8800] BOUND: /127.0.0.1:8800
INFO  [pool-8-thread-1] (org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer$NettyServerAvroHandler.handleUpstream:171)  - [id: 0x00633e5e, /127.0.0.1:56177 => /127.0.0.1:8800] CONNECTED: /127.0.0.1:56177
```

Please help me with this issue. How should I get the logger statements from java standalone application in Flume server console?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The downloaded files for Flume server was not complete. I was missing Flume.bat in D:\apache-flume-1.3.1-bin\bin folder. So I got the window based apache flume server file downloaded once again. You can download it [here](http://abloz.com/flume/windows_download.html)

Set FLUME_HOME in flume.bat file which is available into D:\apache-flume-1.3.1-bin\bin folder.
Now in command prompt, under D:\apache-flume-1.3.1-bin\bin run flume.bat to start flume server.

Now when I run the client application, all the logger statements are shown in flume server console and the file appender mentioned in flume server log4j.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to see the log events in the server console? When you have your system running at full capacity that is a lot of events and you will unnecessarily slow down your system.

I would recommend using the Flume file roll sink to output the events to a log file so that you can confirm they are getting through.

If you really want, you can turn up the logging on the Flume server itself. I think DEBUG or TRACE level will start producing a lot of information about what's happening - including the actual log message.

Update
I think you are confusing two things.

1. Flume transports and stores log statements. Generally, those log statements are sent from the source system using a logging framework like log4j. Flume can then store them - for example in files using file_role sink.
2. Flume itself logs its behaviour. It, too, uses log4j and will write to a file. However, there is nothing in the Flume docs about Flume writing the events it is transporting to its own log.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sarge. Actually it is not printing in both log file as well as console. As a first step in this I tried to come up with printing the log messages in console. If it is going to work, then I thought to work for printing into file. Problem is log4j.properties in flume server is not accessed while connecting to server via standalone java application.

Comment: This has nothing to do with log4j.properties. You need to edit your flume.conf and add the file roll sink.

Comment: Yes am using file_roll. Only the server contents are getting appended into this. But the logger statements(avro) is not available in the server side log file.

Comment: Means the logger statements from console is not getting printed into these server log files. In server log file I could see only the connection is established, open, bound....

Comment: I think you are confusing two things.